# flutter_libserialport write OK but read unhandled exception

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a simple at cmd application.
I modified the flutter_libserialport example.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libserialport

simply,

1. replace the floatButton action to my own reTest() function

```
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        // onPressed: initPorts,
        onPressed: rwTest,
    ),
```

2. and my rwTest below,

```
    Future<void> rwTest() async {
        for (var p in availablePorts) {
          if (p == 'COM115') {
            print(p);
            List<int> d = [65, 84, 13];
            Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(d);
            SerialPort port = SerialPort(p);
            SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port, timeout: 10000);
            try {
              port.openReadWrite();
              print(port.write(bytes));
              await reader.stream.listen((data) {
                print('received : $data');
              });
              port.close();
            } on SerialPortError catch (_, err) {
              if (port.isOpen) {
                port.close();
                print('serial port error');
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

my device is shown as COM115 so I put the fixed value.
and the "write" operation was success
but when I use "reader.stream.listen()"

SerialPortError occurs as below
flutter: COM115
flutter: 3
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SerialPortError: ÀÛ¾÷À» ¿Ï·áÇß½À´Ï´Ù., errno = 0

I guess the usage of "listen" was wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.
anyone can help me to fix it?

Comment: Hey, did you find your solution? Can you share it with us?

Answer (score 1):

The serial port need to open as far as the communication is active to send and receive data

Remove the port close method call

```
try {
    port.openReadWrite();
    print(port.write(bytes));
    await reader.stream.listen((data) {
        print('received : $data');
    });
    //port.close(); --> remove this line
}
```

On exit close the reader stream and then close the port

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `port.close()` in `try{}` ... and I think you should also set the timeout = 1,

Also, it is better to set a configuration before using the port

Note: you can just access the port through name, without looping over all the available ports.

```
Future<void> rwTest() async {
    List<int> d = [65, 84, 13];
    Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(d);
    SerialPort port = SerialPort('COM115');
    // configuration 
    final configu = SerialPortConfig();
    configu.baudRate = 9600;
    configu.bits = 8;
    configu.parity = 0;
    port.config = configu;
    SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port, timeout: 10);
    try {
      port.openReadWrite();
      print(port.write(bytes));
      await reader.stream.listen((data) {
        print('received : $data');
      });
    } on SerialPortError catch (_, err) {
      if (port.isOpen) {
        port.close();
        print('serial port error');
      }
    }
  }
```